# How do I save it as a db file in android's mediastore?

Tags: android

I am trying to save a sqlite db file

so

```
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/vnd.sqlite3");

values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/x-sqlite3");
```

I did the above, but I get the following error

```
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain");
```

If you change to, it will be saved but the extension will change to.

How do I specify MIME.TYPE to save as .db?

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint
> failed: file._data )code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE[2067])

Comment: This may have a similar unique key in the db already.

Answer (score 0):

Convert all your database data into `JSON` format, and store as plain text file `text/json`.